# BIDS 2008 SSIS Package Failing on Windows 7 64, PervasiveOLEDB.11.0 provider is not registered

Tags: ssis, oledb, bids, pervasive-sql

I have a BIDS 2008 SSIS Package accessing a Pervasive SQL database using the Pervasive PSQL OLE DB Provider.

The package was failing validation at run time with the following message in the Execution Results tab:

**Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'PervasiveOLEDB.11.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I had verified that the Pervasive OLE DB provider had been successfully registered, BIDS was running my package under the 64 Bit Runtime, thus not finding a suitably registered 64-bit provider.

This was easily solved by going to the Project Properties > Debugging and setting the "Run64BitRuntime" to **False**.

Thanks to Miguel Salles on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/920a0817-d9b8-4766-b0bf-baa6430acf93/) for the insight.